# Can this code produce memory leak?

Tags: javascript, node.js, memory-leaks

Looks like i found memory leak in my code, but i'm not sure, and i don't have so many experience with nodejs memory leaks.

Can someone explain me, can this code produce memory leak?

```
    var tasks = [];

    // each 10 seconds
    tasks.push(function () { 
            console.log('hello, world!'); 
    });

    // each minute
    while (tasks.length) {
            var task = tasks.shift();
            task();
    }
```

**UPD:** Missed while loop in my code, updated now.

My question is, will scope of my anonymous function from array cleared from memory?

Comment: We need to see more of the surrounding code. Ideally, an [MCVE](/help/mcve). It matters because it matters what the context is where these are being created, removed, etc. But making a few reasonable assumptions, there's no *leak* per se there, it's just that you're adding functions **a lot** faster than you're removing them, so the amount of memory use increases over time. Not a *leak*, because you're intentionally keeping references to those functions, but definitely something to look at.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, not a memory leak but you're putting new elements in your array 6 times faster than you are retrieving them.
As a result, you will actually be using only one out of 5 pushed functions, and your array will keep growing.
If you let it run long enough, you'll end up with a massive array that can never be emptied.

**EDIT:** After you added the `while` loop, the array is not growing anymore, and it shouldn't have any memory leak coming from this part of your code. It does not mean there is none in your project. Make sure any value created in your pushed functions can properly be garbage collected (i.e. that you did not keep a reference on it somewhere).

Comment: I updated now my example, missed while loop in previous time. Yes, array will increase, but will scope of my anonymous function from array cleared from memory? It's what i want to know.

Comment: @user4176305 Yes. If you do not keep any reference on it, the anonymous function and his scope will be garbage collected. There is no memory leak here.